# mlabel command not found

Tags: 14.04, command-line

I get the error

```
mlabel command not found
```

I tried using `sudo apt-get install mlabel`, but it said unable to locate package mlabel.

Any ideas how to get this working?

Comment: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/mtools

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `mlabel` command is provided by the `mtools` package as you can see from http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=mlabel. Therefore, you should install `mtools` instead:

```
sudo apt-get install mtools
```